# Firebase: FIRUser not found on Swift 4

Tags: ios, iphone, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift4

I've started using Firebase and I followed Ray Wenderlich [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/139322/firebase-tutorial-getting-started-2).

After that I created my own project and there nothing works anymore.
I've installed the Firebase pods, I created a bridge header for Firebase framework (like in tutorial). It didn't work so I removed it and I made simply import.

I can import the Firebase in my class but when I try to add :

`FIRUser` or `Firebase.User` (like in the Firebase Authentication [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/naming-migration-guide))

it doesn't work. I have not a lot of choices there... I can't do anything (see the attached photo).

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the documentation states, when migrating to the latest version of the SDK for Swift, remove any `FIR` prefix, so `FIRUser` becomes `User`. You can find the reference [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes#user).

Comment: You're right, thank you! I tried User but I was redirect to my own class.

Comment: You can specify the Firebase module first. like this   private func getFirebaseToken(user: FirebaseAuth.User) {